# Как получить состояние переключателя switch JavaScript? Надо узнать что выбрано ::after или ::before

Tags: javascript

Имеется пример кода на странице сайта. Подскажите пожалуйста, как при помощи внедряемого скрипта js получить состояние переключателя `switch`?
 Надо узнать, что выбрано `::after` или `::before` ?

```html
<span class="switch">
    <label for="NotificationCreate">
        <input id="NotificationCreate" class="switch-toggle switch-toggle-round" type="checkbox" onclick="return NotificationCreateCheckbox_Click.call(this);" value="1" name="NotificationsAllowed_272206075"></input>
        <span class="switch-toggle-round-ui">
            ::before
            ::after
        </span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Или получить хотя бы цвет переключателя, который меняется в зависимости от состояния переключателя. Когда выбран ::before, становится зеленым.

Answer (score 1):

```js
NotificationCreateCheckbox_Click = function(){
  console.log((this.checked) ? '::after' : '::before');
}
```

```html
<span class="switch">
    <label for="NotificationCreate">
        <input id="NotificationCreate" class="switch-toggle switch-toggle-round" type="checkbox" onclick="return NotificationCreateCheckbox_Click.call(this);" value="1" name="NotificationsAllowed_272206075">
        <span class="switch-toggle-round-ui">
            ::before
            ::after
        </span>
</label>
</span>
```